# Some sort of loop to move NULL values to last column in a number of columns?

Tags: sql

I'm returning 4 columns in my query, each of which can contain information or be a NULL value. Is there a way to create some sort of loop so that for each row, all the non-NULL values are moved the left most columns with the NULLs at the end? Or perhaps with the use of functions?

My situation:

| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | NULL | 1 |
| 6 | NULL | NULL | 3 |

My desired result:

| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | NULL |
| 6 | 3 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: I'd consider re-designing instead, perhaps one value per row.

Comment: I've added both PostgreSQL and MySQL answers.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the interesting comments, this can be done, probably in most RDMS as long as they support array functions. (There will be variation in *how* it's done). I made the example table more complicated to show more possible cases.

---

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  "value_1" INTEGER,
  "value_2" INTEGER,
  "value_3" INTEGER,
  "value_4" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t
  ("value_1", "value_2", "value_3", "value_4")
VALUES
  ('5', '3', null, '1'),
  ('6', null, null, '3'),
  ('3', '2', '1', '0'),
  (null, '2', null, '4'),
  (null, null, '3', '4'),
  (null, '3', '4', '5'),
  (null, null, null, '4');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT all_vals[1] Value_1
     , all_vals[2] Value_2
     , all_vals[3] Value_3
     , all_vals[4] Value_4
FROM (
    SELECT array_remove(ARRAY[value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4], NULL) all_vals
    FROM t
) arrs;
```

| value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |  |
| 6 | 3 |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 |  |  |
| 3 | 4 |  |  |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qBarkkEJj3rhtjkcyW2C9d/0)

---

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `value_1` INTEGER,
  `value_2` INTEGER,
  `value_3` INTEGER,
  `value_4` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t
  (`value_1`, `value_2`, `value_3`, `value_4`)
VALUES
  ('5', '3', null, '1'),
  ('6', null, null, '3'),
  ('3', '2', '1', '0'),
  (null, '2', null, '4'),
  (null, null, '3', '4'),
  (null, '3', '4', '5'),
  (null, null, null, '4');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT all_values -> "$[0]" value_1
     , all_values -> "$[1]" value_2
     , all_values -> "$[2]" value_3
     , all_values -> "$[3]" value_4
FROM ( -- The Ordering here matters, as they appear to change the index when removed, so I had to work back to front. 
       -- $[4] (Or any value outside the range) is necessary, as a NULL will cause the whole thing to return NULL.
  SELECT JSON_REMOVE(JSON_ARRAY(value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4) 
                     , CASE WHEN value_4 IS NULL THEN "$[3]" ELSE "$[4]" END
                     , CASE WHEN value_3 IS NULL THEN "$[2]" ELSE "$[4]" END
                     , CASE WHEN value_2 IS NULL THEN "$[1]" ELSE "$[4]" END
                     , CASE WHEN value_1 IS NULL THEN "$[0]" ELSE "$[4]" END
                    ) all_values
  FROM t) arr;
```

| value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |  |
| 6 | 3 |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 |  |  |
| 3 | 4 |  |  |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qBarkkEJj3rhtjkcyW2C9d/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this case, data in a column will be shuffled. For example; "Value_1" can contains date, int, char data types. That is just weird, but you jsut solved it :). It is good to know.